# Wordpress RSS Parser

Tags: f#, rss, asp.net-core

Follow Up to my [earlier question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/172821/41243).

This is an RSS Parser intended only to parse the feed Wordpress provides (and even then, only what I actually want to display on my website). `System.Linq.Xml` and `System.ServiceModel.Syndication` are unavailable because I'm targeting .Net Core instead of the full framework.

I think I've achieved a more idiomatic implementation this time. Where can I improve? Are there opportunities to compose higher order functions that I'm missing?

#### Rss.fs

```
module Rss
    open System

    type Item = {
        Title: string
        Link: Uri
        Comments: Uri
        PublishDate: DateTimeOffset
        Description: string
    }

    type Channel = {
        Title: string
        Link: Uri
        Description: string
        LastBuildDate: DateTimeOffset
        Items: seq<Item>
    }

    type RssFeed = {
        Version: double
        Channel: Channel
    }

    open System.Xml
    let parse input =

        // Helper Functions
        let innerText (elementName: string) (node: XmlNode) =
            let element = node.Item elementName
            element.InnerText

        let titleText node =
            node |> innerText "title"

        let descriptionText node =
            node |> innerText "description"

        let elementAsDateTimeOffset elementName node =
            node |> innerText elementName |> DateTimeOffset.Parse

        let elementAsUri elementName node =
            node |> innerText elementName |> Uri

        let linkUri node =
            node |> elementAsUri "link"

        let itemNodeToItem node = {
            Title = node |> titleText
            Link =  node |> linkUri
            Comments = node |> elementAsUri "comments"
            PublishDate = node |> elementAsDateTimeOffset "pubDate"
            Description = node |> descriptionText
         }

        // Load the document and begin parsing
        let document = XmlDocument()
        document.LoadXml input

        let rss = document.DocumentElement
        let channelNode = rss.FirstChild

        let items =
            channelNode.ChildNodes
            |> Seq.cast<XmlNode>
            |> Seq.filter (fun node -> node.Name.Equals "item")
            |> Seq.map itemNodeToItem

        let channel = {
            Title = channelNode |> titleText
            Link = channelNode |> linkUri
            Description = channelNode |> descriptionText
            LastBuildDate = channelNode |> elementAsDateTimeOffset "lastBuildDate"
            Items = items
        }

        let version =
            (rss.Attributes.ItemOf "version").Value
            |> Double.Parse

        let rssFeed = {Version = version; Channel = channel}
        rssFeed
```

#### Controllers/BlogController.fs

```
namespace theupsyde.Controllers

open System
open System.Collections.Generic
open System.Linq
open System.Threading.Tasks
open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc
open Rss
open System.Net

type BlogController () =
    inherit Controller()

    let fetchUrl url = async {
        let req = WebRequest.Create(Uri(url)) 
        use! resp = req.GetResponseAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask
        use stream = resp.GetResponseStream() 
        use reader = new IO.StreamReader(stream) 
        return reader.ReadToEnd()
    }

    let rssFeed =
        fetchUrl "https://christopherjmcclellan.wordpress.com/feed/" 
        |> Async.RunSynchronously
        |> Rss.parse

    let recent =
        rssFeed.Channel.Items

    member this.Index () =
        this.View(rssFeed.Channel)

    member this.Recent() =
        this.PartialView("BlogPosts", recent)

    member this.Latest () =
        let latest = 
            recent
            |> Seq.head

        this.PartialView("BlogPost", latest)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- The `Rss` helper functions are inside the `parse` function, even though they don't use any of the state inside that scope. Consider moving these up to the module level, even though they are not used anywhere else. By doing this the main function is shorter and easier to follow. You could also make those functions private when you pull them out.
- `Seq.cast` can throw an exception. Even though you know that every item will be an `XmlNode` in this case, it can be safer to filter out objects that are not of the required type while casting. Unfortunately, F# doesn't have a function for this in the `Seq` module but you can always use the one already in .NET: `channelNode.ChildNodes |> System.Linq.Enumerable.OfType<XmlNode>`
- You fetch the RSS feed in the constructor of `BlogController`. This will happen once for each request. Using `Async.RunSynchronously` will block a thread, so you lose the benefit of using `Async` in the first place. You should avoid `Async.RunSynchronously` whenever you can. You can pull out the RSS fetching and parsing into another function that returns an `async`. Call this function from each controller method, do more async processing if necessary and then use `Async.StartAsTask` to return a task from the method. ASP.NET will then be able to run your code without unnecessary blocking.

**EDIT:**

I'm not too familiar with ASP.NET MVC, but based on [this issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/5570) I *think* something like this should work:

```
let fetchRss() = async {
    let! content = fetchUrl "https://christopherjmcclellan.wordpress.com/feed/" 
    return Rss.parse content }

type BlogController() =
    inherit Controller()

    member this.Index() = async {
        let! rss = fetchRss()
        return this.View(rss.Channel) }
```

Comment: Thanks for the review. I was struggling with the async and I had a feeling I was blocking... Could I trouble you to show me what you mean? A small example of how to do it right would really help me out.

Comment: @RubberDuck See my edit

Comment: Thanks. That was close. It needs to be something like `member this.Index () = Async.StartAsTask(async {...})`. It's a bit ugly, but properly converts the Async<'a> into a Task<T> and runs everything asynchronously.

Answer (score 5):

So [TheQuickBrownFox](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/125531/thequickbrownfox) is [spot on when they mention the potential exception with `Seq.Cast<'T>`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/172954/73844), and I want to talk about that and introduce a couple new operators to you.

The potential problem lies in the fact that it *could* be possible for an item to not be castable to `XmlNode`, and then we throw exceptions [which is usually frowned upon in F#](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/exceptions/), we would instead want to return an error state.

One of the [many operators](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/symbol-and-operator-reference/) in F# is the `:?` operator, which tests if a value is castable to the specified type. (So `x :? XmlNode` will test if `x` is an `XmlNode`.) We can thing of this as analogous to the `is` operator in C#.

So I want to write a `castSafe` method which will cast our object list to a type, *without* throwing an exception. We intend to use this as `channelNode.ChildNodes |> Seq.castSafe<XmlNode>`.

The first step is to define the type-structure of our function, which I'll define as `IEnumerable -> 'T option seq`. We also want to define what happens if an invalid cast is attempted? I'm going to return a [`'T option`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/options), that defines the result. If it's [`Some 'T`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/12f048d2-e293-4596-accb-de036ecd63fc), then we casted successfully, if it's [`None`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/83ef260a-aa33-4e6f-aee6-b9bf0a461476), then we didn't.

A basic, lazy implementation might look as follows:

```
let castSafe<'T> (items:IEnumerable) : 'T option seq =
    items
    |> Seq.cast<obj>
    |> Seq.map (fun node ->
        match node with
        | :? 'T as result -> Some result
        | _ -> None)
```

So we're immediately casting to `obj` to allow the type-system to make it's next move. Since `XmlNodeList` doesn't implement `IEnumerable<T>` we can't enumerate each item as an `XmlNode`: we have to enumerate as an `obj`. Then we `match` on the type: `:? 'T` says "Is `node` a `'T` type?" If it's a yes, then we return `Some result` which is the node *casted as `'T`*, if not we return a `None`.

Of course this means on the client-side we would have to test for `Some node` or `None`, which we don't want to do. So we'll also build a `castSafeFilter` which will cast to `'T` and remove the `None` entires. A naive implementation could look as follows:

```
let castSafeFilter<'T> (items:IEnumerable) : 'T seq =
    items
    |> castSafe
    |> Seq.filter (fun node ->
        match node with
        | Some x -> true
        | None -> false)
    |> Seq.map (fun node -> node.Value)
```

But we don't want to do that: we're casting then testing for `Some`/`None`, but there's a more effective manner: we can filter first. Enter the `:?>` operator. This will do a direct cast to a type lower in the type hierarchy, that is: this will do a *runtime cast* to a sub-type. (So if we cast `XmlNode -> obj`, this let's us go back to `XmlNode`.) I **wish** this were synonymous with the `as` operator in C#, but it's more like an explicit cast: `(T)obj`.

Our new function looks something like this:

```
let castSafeFilter<'T> (items:IEnumerable) : 'T seq =
    items
    |> Seq.cast<obj>
    |> Seq.filter (fun node -> node :? 'T)
    |> Seq.map (fun node -> node :?> 'T)
```

Do the `<obj>` cast immediately, but then *filter out all non-`'T` items* then cast.

By doing it like this we eliminate the double-map, and do a single map to `'T` **if and only if** it is a `'T`. More interesting: we can add these two methods directly to the `Seq` module *just as if they were extension methods*:

```
module Seq
    open System.Collections

    let castSafe<'T> (items:IEnumerable) : 'T option seq =
        items
        |> Seq.cast<obj>
        |> Seq.map (fun node ->
            match node with
            | :? 'T as result -> Some result
            | _ -> None)

    let castSafeFilter<'T> (items:IEnumerable) : 'T seq =
        items
        |> Seq.cast<obj>
        |> Seq.filter (fun node -> node :? 'T)
        |> Seq.map (fun node -> node :?> 'T)
```

*Usually* I would omit type-annotations, but when building a generic, multi-purpose module I always keep them. We could define an `fsi` file instead that would contain all the signatures, but that's beyond the scope of what I wish to explain here.

Finally, we're back to our code, you had:

> ```
> let items =
>     channelNode.ChildNodes
>     |> Seq.cast<XmlNode>
>     |> Seq.filter (fun node -> node.Name.Equals "item")
>     |> Seq.map itemNodeToItem
> ```

We're going to change that to:

```
let items =
    channelNode.ChildNodes
    |> Seq.castSafeFilter<XmlNode>
    |> Seq.filter (fun node -> node.Name.Equals "item")
    |> Seq.map itemNodeToItem
```

And bam, now we have *safely* casted the items to an `XmlNode`, and allowed ourselves a great deal of reuse in the future.

And finally, with some extra cleverness, we could even devise a `castFilter` method, that would test if our `node` is a `'T`, and if so do the filtering *at that level* to avoid redundant calls. That is:

```
let castFilter<'T> (filter:'T -> bool) (items:IEnumerable) : 'T seq =
    items
    |> Seq.cast<obj>
    |> Seq.filter (fun node -> 
        match node with
        | :? 'T as result -> result |> filter
        | _ -> false)
    |> Seq.map (fun node -> node :?> 'T)
```

And *interestingly* if we work with `result` on the filter at that point, the `:? 'T as result` tests if `node` is a `'T`, **and** does the `node :?> 'T` cast for us, so we've finally achieved the same functionality as the C# `as` keyword.

And as mentioned in comments, using [`Seq.choose`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/seq.choose%5B't,'u%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D) is another great alternative, which opens us up to a little bit of extraction:

```
let private castItemSafe<'T> (item:obj) : 'T option =
    match item with
    | :? 'T as result -> Some result
    | _ -> None

let castSafe<'T> (items:IEnumerable) : 'T option seq =
    items
    |> Seq.cast<obj>
    |> Seq.map castItemSafe

let castSafeFilter<'T> (items:IEnumerable) : 'T seq =
    items
    |> Seq.cast<obj>
    |> Seq.choose castItemSafe
```

*Because* of the nature of our casting, we really only need to store the function which casts an individual item in one spot, since `map` will return all items and `choose` will naturally filter them out.

---

I [previously touched on some basic composition stuff](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/172821/rss-parser-for-blog-feed/172864#172864), and I want to continue that discussion with some new examples here.

We have opportunity to use some [function composition](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/function-composition/) in this code, which lends us to partial application, and allow us to *not care about the node parameter* to our functions.

For example, we can take your `titleText` and `descriptionText` functions and *simply omit the `node` parameter* and our functions still work the same, thus leaving them agnostic to what's applied *even moreso* than they were. But what if we want to omit node from `elementAsDateTimeOffset`? Well we can't really do that as it's written, because the pipe-right (`|>`) operator expects a *value*, not a function. Now we can use the compose-right (`>>`) operator to eliminate that requirement:

```
let titleText =
    innerText "title"

let descriptionText =
    innerText "description"

let elementAsDateTimeOffset elementName =
    innerText elementName >> DateTimeOffset.Parse

let elementAsUri elementName =
    innerText elementName >> Uri

let linkUri =
    elementAsUri "link"
```

Now here is the part I really like: none of our signatures changed, but we no longer care about the parameter itself in these functions. We've *partially* applied the functions. For example, on `titleText` it is simply applying the `"title"` string to the `innerText` function (which expects two parameters) and returning a function that just needs an `XmlNode` applied to it.

I like to use this more and more in my code as it seems a bit clearer to me in the end. The net result is the same, and there's no significant advantage (that I know of - do note I'm no expert) to using one over the other, but it becomes a preference on the developer's end. (This also lends itself *very* easily towards the introduction of [currying](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/currying/): that is, every function has one and only one parameter, even those with multiple parameters.)

Comment: An alternative implementation: `let castSafeFilter<'T> = Seq.map box >> Seq.choose (function :? 'T as x -> Some x | _ -> None)`. But even better: `let castSafeFilter<'T> = System.Linq.Enumerable.OfType<'T>`. I think it's more idiomatic to use an existing .NET method instead of re-writing it :)

Comment: I'm unlikely to use the safe cast here, as I'm guaranteed that `XmlNodeList` only contains `XmlNode`s, but it was highly educational none the less. Thank you. I'll see if I can grok your partial application suggestions later.

Comment: @RubberDuck I don't blame you there - I'm not saying this is the better idea, all I wanted to point at is that it *is* possible to build something like this that *feels* natural, allowing us to expand on what the language already does. :)

Comment: The partial application thing worked great. It was neat to see how it didn't change the signature of the function. Now I just need to figure out how/when I can leverage partial application in my code in general. You're a great teacher. Thanks again!